# Django template implementation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, templates

Does anyone know about an extensible django template implementation in javascript. I don't need all the advanced features, but loops, tags and filters would be nice.

I found a few projects/hacks just implementing the variable style but that's not enough for us.

The one that came closest is: http://code.google.com/p/jtl-javascript-template/ but it's not very well written/complete/maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this : http://icanhazjs.com/

And here how it can work with django : http://tothinkornottothink.com/post/4282971041/using-jquery-templating-icanhaz-js-with-django

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) and [pystache](https://github.com/defunkt/pystache). It would require some changes as the feature set isn't as powerful as Django templates but it does provide [fair amount of freedom](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html).